# Cycles Volume Scattering totally black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I have an issue with volume scattering in cycles. I modeled and textured a model in Blender Render engine and moved it to the Cycles Render engine for render, I ran into a problem with volume scattering. The final render with this option becomes impenetrable dark.

My model in cycles has default material (diffuse bsdf)
For lightning source I use a spot lamp (not sun or hemi)

CPU rendering

Computer specs:

64 bit 8 RAM

Intel(R)_Pentium(R)_CPU_G2030_@_3.00GHz

AMD Radeon R7 200 Series

[image: Blender Render engine]

[image: Cycles Render engine]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The density (Volume panel in World) was set to a very high value. Setting it to 0.001 instead of 0.100, will make volume scattering be visible.